# Are dram ssds more vulnerable to power outages?

Tags: ssd

High-end SSDs have built-in DRAM modules to improve performance and drive life.  In the event of sudden power outages are they more exposed to data corruption than dramless ones as RAM is a volatile memory or are there systems (capacitors for example) capable of preventing this eventuality?

Comment: If you are worried about power outages then get a UPS.  How often do you get them anyway?  And the answer would depend on how they have been put together - ie different manufacturers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many SSDs do have supercaps to allow them to flush data – or even to complete at least the flash memory write.

(Consider that an interrupted write to flash storage can also lead to corruption – not just of the sector but also of the whole page, from what I've heard – so it's not entirely "better" to not have DRAM; power loss is bad either way.)

Hardware RAID array controllers also often have DRAM cache before the HDD, and they have rechargeable batteries to prevent data loss.

Kingston has an article about this; https://www.kingston.com/en/blog/servers-and-data-centers/ssd-power-loss-protection

Comment: Many *enterprise* lvl SSD's AFAIK. I wouldn't count on their presence in consumer lvl SSD.